# ubuntu 20.04 only boots from recovery mode

Tags: ubuntu, system-recovery

After a power outage, my ubuntu 20.04 boots from the normal option in grub to a black screen and hangs there.

However, if I go to Advanced Options and select recovery mode and then "resume", it is able to boot up.

What went wrong? how can I fix it?

Note: I found many solutions to this problem, not all worked for me so I figure that there are many things that could go wrong. It might be nice to have many optional solutions listed in the answers for this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was reinstalling all the `nvidia` drivers.

- Uninstall all `nvidia` drivers (based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely))

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
  echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
  ```
- Reinstall all `nvidia` drivers (based on [this thread](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux))

  ```
  ubuntu-drivers devices
  sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
  ```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was not to install all the `nvidia` drivers, but only the 470 version.

At this moment the newest driver version available for me is 520.
However, this version or the 515 did not work.

To install the 470 you can write:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
sudo reboot
```

Then my Ubutu 20.04 boots normally, without need of the recovery mode. It also recognizes the second screen (if available) properly.

Answer (score 0):

Update: https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Re-installed Lubunutu, worked for a bit after latest update, black screen on boot (same issue) [6.5.0-15-generic].

Using old kernel seems to be working. /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 6.0.2-26-generic'
```

Easiest solution seemed to be just change boot order.

Old chromebook running seabios, starting to realize minimizing my time dinking with it, is my best use of time.

---

Old:

On 22.04 LTS

Since 'recovery mode' selection in GRUB worked.  I tried to find the differences between it and simple.

```
sudo emacs /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Then I went to first menu entry

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simp\
le-f9e7bb1f-0488-4981-bcdc-364955555550'
```

For me, I had to remove the line (comment)

```
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
```

And add `nomodeset` to the kernel command line parameters.

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic root=UUID=f9e7bb1f-0488-4981-bcdc-364955555550 ro nomodeset
```

Just simply setting `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub` didn't fix it, also needed to remove `gfxmode`, and couldn't figure out how to do without manually editing the `.cfg` file.

I tried many other things, but working backward from the 'recovery mode' is what worked best, so I don't have to sit there finger on the trigger at boot up.